# Click and hover - text show on click?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mouseevent, toggle

At the moment this all works fine apart from when the item is clicked the inner text does not display. It only works on `mouseover` and `mouseleave`. I have tried using unbind on `mouseleave` but this does not seem to work.

How do I get it to work when the item is clicked?

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ydeqL8v/1/).

```
$('.item').on({
    mouseover: function() {
        if ($(this).closest('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
            $(this).parent('.highlight').addClass("hovered");
            $(this).siblings('.inner').addClass("display");
        }
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        if ($(this).closest('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
            $(this).parent('.highlight').removeClass("hovered");
            $(this).siblings('.inner').removeClass("display");
        }
    }
});

$('.highlight').on('click', '.item', function(e) {
    if ($(this).closest('.timelineTile').hasClass("clicked")) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.item').not(this).removeClass('canceled');
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('canceled');
        $(this).parent().removeClass('hovered');
        $(this).siblings('.inner').removeClass("display");

    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is, if you're using both click and mouse leave events, they will create a conflict. The text will show on click, but will disappear on mouse leave.

Answer (score 0):

See if `this` is what you're looking for... **[updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/8ydeqL8v/9/)**

Comment: this is more what i mean - i've managed to get it to this point http://jsfiddle.net/f6rbped1/ however the 'inner' text is removed by hover not by click.